# Erro de execução no projeto em React Native no Windows

Tags: react-native, syntax-error

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: **inserir a descrição da imagem aqui**]Eu gostaria de saber o porque e como resolver esse erro.

Comment: Seu server não está rodando. Tente novamente rodar o comando: react-native start 
Se tudo ocorrer bem, tente o comando: react-native run-android

Comment: Eu tentei, mas mesmo assim o server não reinicia

Comment: creio que seja melhor reinstalar e configurar o ambiente, amigo. :/

Comment: obrigado, mas aqui está a imagem do erro de quando executo "react-native start"

Comment: Parece ser um problema de compatibilidade entre a sua versão do Node e a versão do seu React Native. Tente seguir as dicas deste post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117377/react-native-start-giving-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-error

Comment: O problema é a versão do Node.js, faz o downgrade para versão mais recente estável que deve funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro é comum no Windows, já me aconteceu uma vez tive que muda manualmente nas versões mas recente do React Native foram ajustado, nesse caso se não for possível atualizar recomendo que altere manualmente, entra no diretório:

> \node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js

substitua a variável **sharedBlacklist**

```
 var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.\/_tests_\/./
];
```